# Cycle Wordpress posts

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wordpress

How do I retrieve the posts from a Wordpress database and display them on a `div` on my web page and have them cycle - similar to the jQuery cycle plugin?

EDIT: I didn't mention that the site is built using ASP.NET not php and I need to access the posts using c#. This hopefully is the reason it has been voted down and voted to close

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Code?

Comment: Uh, how does this have anything to do with asp.net?

Comment: @elclanrs - what have I tried? I am a complete noob to wordpress. I have managed to integrate it into my asp.net site but I have no idea how to programatically retrieve the posts from the database. So no I haven't tried code. I was hoping there might there might be a plugin that could do this for me

Comment: @skimberk1 - the wordpress is integrated into an asp.net site

Comment: You could start by searching in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: why is my question so bad that it is voted down and asked to close?

Comment: Well, just read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: hmmmm...just did. What part of FAQ are you referring to? From what I can see my question avoids 'What question not to ask' and also 'why are some questions closed'..it fits into ' your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.' - could someone please tell me why my question is inappropriate and should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those of you interested this link seems to have some useful information about how to both post and get from wordpress using asp.net

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=419